# Unable to route using blueprint Flask

Tags: python, flask

I followed the instructions in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#blueprints and tried to     do the routing in another script other than the script in which I created the app object . But I get error as

"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

It just ignores the routing that I did in that script .

```
restservice = Blueprint('restservice', __name__,template_folder='templates')

@restservice.route('/')
def approot():
   render_template('timeline.html')
```

Comment: Please run your app with debugging enabled (`app.run(debug=True)`) and post the traceback here.

Comment: Ya , with your app.run(debug=True) debugging technique i was able to sort out the mistake by myself . With this debugging i found that the blue print was not ignored , but the problem was within the module . And this got printed in the log with this debugging technique . Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your blueprint is in a file called restservice.py, you need to add these lines in the file where you created the app object

```
from restservice import restservice as restModule
app.register_blueprint(restModule)
```